# Sitecore Identity Server: Azure AD: Nonce was null

Tags: identity-server, federated-authentication

Sitecore Identity Server: Azure AD: Nonce was null. Looking to see if others encountered this issue with Sitecore 9.3. I can output the claims for the logged in user but then it throws an exception re: Nonce cookie. I don't have access to Azure AD directly and limited help. I've seen some talk about: App.UseKentorOwinCookieSaver - is that still needed?

```
22076 12:09:54 WARN  An error with Nonce cookie occured.
Exception: Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectProtocolInvalidNonceException
Message: IDX21323: RequireNonce is '[PII is hidden]'. OpenIdConnectProtocolValidationContext.Nonce was null, OpenIdConnectProtocol.ValidatedIdToken.Payload.Nonce was not null. The nonce cannot be validated. If you don't need to check the nonce, set OpenIdConnectProtocolValidator.RequireNonce to 'false'. Note if a 'nonce' is found it will be evaluated.
Source: Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.OpenIdConnect
```

Comment: We had this same issue and it was caused because we set `SameSite=strict` on each cookie. Do you see the Nonce cookie when Azure AD comes back to Sitecore?

Comment: I had this issue when i started integrating with AdB2C , I used incognito mode + cleared browser cache to resolve this